# Omnifaces CombinedResourceHandler order in POST and GET

Tags: jsf-2.2, myfaces, omnifaces

I'm using CombinedResourceHandler alone

```
<application>         
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

With some excluded resources:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And I have this simple page:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html" >
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-bootstrap" name="theme.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/icons/icons.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet  name="font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <o:form>
            <o:messages></o:messages>
            <h:inputText required="true" id='somefield'/>
            <h:commandButton></h:commandButton>
        </o:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

When the request is GET I have this css order (production mode):

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bootstrap"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/eNorKMrMTU1LTE4t1k3Kzy8pLilKLLAqyUjNTdVLLi6uAWL9zOT8PCgJEgMA_HITwQ.css.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&amp;v=1441782365350"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css.xhtml"/>
```

And when is POST:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bootstrap"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css.xhtml"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/travelc/javax.faces.resource/eNorKMrMTU1LTE4t1k3Kzy8pLilKLLAqyUjNTdVLLi6uAWL9zOT8PCgJEgMA_HITwQ.css.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.combined&amp;v=1441782365350"/>
```

Which breaks the page. How can I prevent this from happening?

I'm using omnifaces latest snapshot and myfaces 2.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced it. MyFaces plays a role here. It works fine with Mojarra.

On postback, the combined resource still exists in the component tree and had to be extracted and re-combined (just to cover the case any resources are conditionally added/removed during postback). However, due to a logic bug, the combined resource was newly created and added to end instead of reusing the earlier combined resource location where it was found, confirming the symptoms you were seeing. The bug would only be noticeable if you're excluding resources from combining, causing that there are multiple resources. It worked in Mojarra because the component ID was the same.

The logic bug is fixed as per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/96d5d171020e653d914e46578fd8bb4ea53b5502) and available as per today's latest OmniFaces 2.2 snapshot.